# Is there an alternative to TBitBtn that scales correctly at higher screen resolutions - or alternative a piece of code that fixes this issue?

Tags: delphi

I am dynamically creating a number of TBitBtn with custom bitmaps. Works nice, except if the screen is high res - which causes positioning and size to change. The other controls on the form are not affected.

Do not know what to try.

```
  BitBbegersopp:= TbitBtn.Create(Form2);
  with BitBbegersopp do
   begin
    Parent:=Form2;
    Glyph.LoadFromFile('beger.bmp');
    OnClick:= BitBbegersoppClick;
    Left:= Start.Left + HDistStartB + 0*HSpacingBitB;
    Height:= HSizeBitB;
    Width:= VSizeBitB;
    Top:= Start.Top + VDistStartB + 0*VSpacingBitB;
    Hint:= 'Begersopp, sporer på oversiden';
    ShowHint:= True;
    Tag:= 1;
   end;
```

Comment: To answer this question you should provide the Delphi version you are working andh and a minimal example (MCVE, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem. At the moment, all I can see is "works nice except .....".

Comment: I am dynamically creating a number of TBitBtn with custom bitmaps. Works nice, except if the screen is high res - which causes positioning and size to change. The other controls on the form are not affected.

Comment: I am using ver 10.2

Comment: It is not easy to share an example, this is about the behavior of Tbitbtn when the program runs - the other controls scale to the actual screen resolution, the bitbtns do not.

Comment: Are the other controls created at run time, too?

Comment: I still don't get it. You are saying that the height and width of the buttons is not scaled? Also it must be easy to make an example. Just one button on a form surely.

Comment: I am a stackoverflow newbie, please excuse me for not being forum-fluent yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you didn't provide an example, which leaves us with a lot of guessing, I can see two problems in your code.

1. The scaling to the current PPI is done inside the assignment to Parent.
2. In case Start is an existing control, its Left and Top properties are already scaled while the offsets used as well as the values for Width and Height are probably not.

To tackle both problems I suggest the following code sequence:

```
  BitBbegersopp:= TbitBtn.Create(Form2);
  with BitBbegersopp do
   begin
    Glyph.LoadFromFile('beger.bmp');
    OnClick:= BitBbegersoppClick;
    { use unscaled values }
    Left:= HDistStartB + 0*HSpacingBitB;
    Height:= HSizeBitB;
    Width:= VSizeBitB;
    Top:= VDistStartB + 0*VSpacingBitB;
    { this will scale the control }
    Parent:=Form2;
    { Now uses scaled values }
    Left:= Start.Left + Left;
    Top:= Start.Top + Top;
    Hint:= 'Begersopp, sporer på oversiden';
    ShowHint:= True;
    Tag:= 1;
   end;
```

BTW, please avoid *with*!

Comment: Thank you, I failed to understand the scaling process, now I see. Sizing and position of the bitbtn is now ok. The problem of the glyph scaling remains; with high screen resolution the glyph is much smaller than with standard resolution. Maybe I should not expect this scale automatically? In such case I assume I need to include a test for system screen resolution and size up or down the glyph bitmaps accordingly?

Comment: Why the 'with' warning? without it there will be a lot of repeated 'Bitbegersopp.' in the code.

Comment: The glyph is not scaled. You have to provide different sized bitmaps for different DPI sizes. Delphi 10.3 introduces a TVirtualImageList for that, but TBitBtn doesn't support it. Perhaps you can switch to TButton?
Regarding "with": http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2004/08/with-statement-considered-harmful.html

Comment: Thank you. I need to use TBitBtn because the graphics on each button is essential (the anatomy of mushrooms) for the user interaction. Should be straightforward to load different DPI bitmaps, it just adds more files & code.

Comment: I will tag as answered, even if I still wonder why not 'with' (when used carefully and in this kind of straightforward code).

Comment: TButton can also display an image. There is rarely a need for TBitBtn anymore.

Comment: I am using VCL, I believe what you are saying is true for FMX? Some day I should probably learn how to move from VCL to FMX.

Comment: No, the VCL TButton can display an image

Comment: Thank you. I have googled around to try to understand how I can load (VCL) TButton with an image, but with no success. I do not understand the concept of imagelist and images property. Would very much appreciate being pointed to an example or explanation.

Comment: Its pretty simple: Drop a TImagelist on the form and add some images. Connect the imagelist to the Images property of the button. Then select the ImageIndex of the button.

Comment: Thank you, this is really powerful.